# Laravel Override View::make namespace, cashier specific

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

How would I override the `View::make('cashier::receipt');` view so that when that particular namespace is called like that, it checks my folder first and then defaults back to the vendor path.

```
View::addNamespace('cashier', [
    '/path/to/my/views', // check first
    '/path/to/original/views' // check second
]);
```

Comment: Or I guess I vendor publish?

Comment: Hey Brian, can you explain more about your particular use case? IE you have a custom view but you don't want to show it all the time, there are some cases where you want to default back to the vendor default? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's how Laravel handles custom views for packages already. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages#views - see Overriding Package Views here.

Laravel registers two locations to load views so they can be easily customised, the standard vendor path and something customisable.

Laravel will first check if a custom version of the view has been provided by you, for example in

```
resources/views/vendor/cashier.
```

Let me know if there was something more specific you were trying to achieve but I believe the info there will get you going.